Can the $\ker T$ and $\ker T\circ T$ be the same?
Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ and $A^2$ have same rank. Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^n}$ defined by $T(V)=AV, \forall V\in \mathbb{R^n}$. which of the following statements are true?
(1) the kernels of T and $T\circ T$ are the same.
(2)The dimension of $T$ and $T\circ T$ are the same
(3) $A$ must be invertible
(4)$In+A$ must be invertible where $In$ denote identity matrix
$A$ and $A^2$ both have same rank does not mean A will be invertible so option 3 is incorrect.
Similarly $In+A$ cannot be necessarily invertible.so option 4 also incorrect.
Since $T(V)=AV$ implies $$(T\circ T)(V)=T(T(V))=T(AV)=A(AV)=A^2V$$
Since the dimension of $A$ and  $A^2$ are the same, ker T and ker $T\circ T $ will also have same dimension.
I am not getting about option 1, I believe kernel can have same dimension but need not be same.  Am I correct??
Thanks in advance!!

What are the "dimension of a linear map" and the "dimension of a matrix"?

1 is proved in this post.

And 2 makes no sense.  As for 3 and 4, your intuition is correct but requires counterexamples, like respectively $A=0$ and $A=-I_n$.

If you want to disprove $3$ and $4$ you should try to come up with counterexamples.
You are close to proving 1. There is one trivial inclusion, and the other can be proved by contradiction.
